# C: Stack implementation of malloc and free

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, logical-operators, comparison-operators

I am reading K&R pointers section 5.4 where a stack implementation of `malloc()` and `free()` are done. I am using gdb to debug the code, and the `alloc()` part is working as expected. But for the `afree()` part, the pointers are still pointing to the same location as before. Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ALLOCSIZE 10000

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];
static char* allocp = allocbuf;

char* alloc(int n)
{
    if(allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n)
    {   
        allocp += n;
        return (allocp - n); 
    }   
    else
        return 0;
}


void afree(char* p)
{
    if(p >= allocbuf && p < allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE)
        allocp = p;
}


int main()
{
    char* a = alloc(10);
    a = "ayushnair";
    char*b = alloc(5);
    b = "snea";
    printf("%p    %p\n", a, b); 
    afree(b);
    afree(a);
    printf("%p    %p\n", a, b); 
    return 0;
}
```

New allocation

> allocp 0x601080

after `char* a = alloc(10);`

> allocp 0x60108a

after `char* b = alloc(5);`

> allocp 0x60108f

after  `afree(b);`

> allocp 0x60108f

after  `afree(a);`

> allocp 0x60108f

`allocp` still points to `0x60108f`. Why does it not update according to the code?

Comment: `return (alloc - n);` is strange: function pointer - `n`?

Comment: @chux Most likely a typo: should be `allocp`.

Comment: Why do you increase `allocp` anyway? You already loose memory, so no need to care about that special condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, by saying

```
a = "ayushnair";
```

you're not storing the `"ayushnair"` *into* the memory pointed by `a`. The `"ayushnair"` is a *string literal* and by saying

```
a = "ayushnair";
```

you're storing the base address of the string literal into `a`. This way, you're essentially overwriting the returned pointer by the call to `alloc()`.

This is not something you want. You may need to use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy the string literal *into* the returned pointer.

That said, as per the current code, later by calling

```
afree(b);
afree(a);
```

you're invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you're trying to comapre pointers that do not point to the same object.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.8, *Relational operators*

> **When two pointers are compared**, the result depends on the relative locations in the
>   address space of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object types both point to the
>   same object, or both point one past the last element of the same array object, they
>   compare equal. If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object,
>   pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members
>   declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript
>   values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values. All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. If the
>   expression P points to an element of an array object and the expression Q points to the
>   last element of the same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than
>   P. **In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Just to add: On your normal PC it will most likely work; what happens is that the pointer value is not inside the static alocation buffer, i.e. `p >= allocbuf && p < allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE` is wrong. Therefore  `allocp`  is not updated.

Comment: "Will work" is relative where UB is involved. ;-) The alloc() / afree() algorithm will *not* work after assigning the string literal. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar You're right sir, but maybe I'm missing your point here. Anything I can add to clarify?

Comment: @Peter A. Schneider So what should be the condition inside that if condition to function correctly

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I think the OP is still unclear about what actually made his code break. Perhaps emphasize on the "C doesn't do string objects", and downplay a bit on the UB (which is, after all, "only" a follow-up problem of the OP's misconception about strings -- he does not *want* to compare pointers not in the same object).

Comment: I've posted an answer of my own.

Comment: @DevSolar Already upvoted, However, in the meantime, I've also added a bit more clarification to my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks @SouravGhosh for clarifying the doubt.

Comment: @aayu5h It's not the condition which is wrong but that you assign a different value to the pointer. Sourav's edits and DevSolar's answer should have clarified that point.

Answer (score 3):

```
char* a = alloc(10);
```

This "allocates" memory from `allocbuf`, and assigns the pointer to that memory to `a`.

```
a = "ayushnair";
```

This assigns a *different* pointer to `a` -- one that points to the string literal `"ayushnair"`, *which is not in `allocbuf`* but somewhere else in memory entirely.

From here on onward your program is just getting more and more confused (especially since you make a similar mistake with `b`). The call to `afree( a )` makes no sense since `a` is no longer pointing to what `alloc()` returned, and the comparison done by `afree()` actually invokes undefined behaviour as Sourav Ghosh pointed out -- but the error is the `a = "ayushnair"` (and the similar assignment to `b`).

---

The language C has no concept of a "string object", just a convention that a pointer to a sequence of `char` that ends with a `'\0'` is called a "string" and has some support functions. A suitable definition of the operator `=` to mean "copy the contents" is **not** part of those support functions.

What you *wanted* to do was:

```
char * a = alloc( 10 );
strcpy( a, "ayushnair" );
```

That would *copy* from the string literal *to* the memory pointed to by `a`.

---

So, bottom line, your problem is not about logical or comparison operators, and not about arrays -- it's about pointers and strings. I hope I was able to clarify a bit.

Answer (score -2):

It does not update pointer(on afee) as this algorithm of mememory allocator is progressive and has "no memory" of previuosly allocated memory parts. Thus returns just pointer to unused memory. After allocating ALLOCSIZE it will not be possible to allocate more mem. Most memory allocators make some assumptions about consumed memory.

Comment: Quite obviously, `allocp` should be updated, but isn't. You are right that the malloc implementation doesn't have a "memory"; the information is in the pointer.

Comment: @Peter A. Schneider Not directlly in pointer, as pointer just points to mem and by itself does not have more info in it, but points to mem where some part may contain additional inline info about occupied mem.